# What would be the relationship between a user table, rating table, and location table?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, database-design, android-sqlite

I am working on a small Android application that will allow a user to create an account, view and rate places that are shown, and save places to be viewed later (that's why I am having them create an account). I am working with an SQLite database and was wondering what the relationship would be between my User table and Location/Place table. My initial thought would be a many to many relationship with a rating table serving as the intersection table. For example, the rating table would store both the ID of the user and place, but also have its own rating ID.

Comment: So the app will have only one user?or many? if the app will have many users then the relationship will be many to many and then you should create a third table to keep both foreign keys of locations and users.

Comment: @ArisPanayiotou The app will have many users. The whole purpose of the app is to provide people the opportunity to rate different places and so many users will be required. I liked the idea of having a user account people that will allow me to save locations for each user of the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the `ER` representation of what I think should be your database design:

[image: ER diagram]

I also added some extra information to `User` and `Rating` to make `ER` diagram more realistic...

According to this design your tables should be like:

- **User**(*id*, *name*, *age*) -> **key**(*id*)
- **Place**(*id*) -> **key**(*id*)
- **Rating**(*User_id*, *Place_id*, *rate*, *time*, *date*) -> **key**(*User_id*, *Place_id*)
- **Saves**(*User_id*, *Place_id*, *rate*, *time*, *date*) -> **key**(*User_id*, *Place_id*)
- ***NOTE***: since `Rating` is a weak entity (it relies both on User and Place) we can extract it from the `Rates` relation since there would be no `Rating` without a `User` and a `Place` involved in it.

hope you find it helpful.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on the idea of the saves table. Why would it need to store a rate? I might not have explained it clearly enough but the idea would be to give users an opportunity to mark certain locations. These locations would then be visible in a separate area so the user wouldn't have to go find them again. Would I need a separate table for this or could this be a field in the user table?

Comment: you cannot do it ... lets assume your user table has a field called "Places To Watch" which stores the place id each user wants to visit ... now if some user wants to visit 2 or more places you cant add them to your table cause you will end up with duplicate ids... I hope you get what I mean ... btw sorry for my poor english

Comment: That makes complete sense. The comments aren’t supposed to be for saying thanks, but thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

---

The tables should be like
`User-> Id,Name,Username,Password

Ratings-> Id,User_id,Location_id,Rating

Location->Id,Name

SavedLocations->Id,User_id,Location_id`

---